# DNS/DHCP server in multi-machine private-network Vagrant setup

Tags: linux, virtualbox, dns, dhcp, vagrant

## Question

Is it possible to configure [vagrant](/questions/tagged/vagrant), using a [multi-machine `Vagrantfile`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/), to have one of the VMs act as the DNS server and DHCP server (i.e. using [`dnsmasq`](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)) for a private network used by all VMs in my private network?

---

## Background

I'm currently using [an example I found as a baseline](https://manski.net/2016/09/vagrant-multi-machine-tutorial/), and DNS resolution via the private network (along with IP communications) works fine. However, I'd like the `master` box to have [`dnsmasq`](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) installed and acting as the DNS/DHCP server for `node1` and `node2`. The overall goal is to have a `Vagrantfile` that can rapidly spin-up such a VM/network configuration as a learning/training tool (i.e. so students can learn how to tinker with  [`dnsmasq`](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)).

---

## Code Listing

```
# Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
# boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
BOX_IMAGE = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
NODE_COUNT = 2

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "master" do |subconfig|
    subconfig.vm.box = BOX_IMAGE
    subconfig.vm.hostname = "master"
    subconfig.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.0.10"
  end

  (1..NODE_COUNT).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "node#{i}" do |subconfig|
      subconfig.vm.box = BOX_IMAGE
      subconfig.vm.hostname = "node#{i}"
      # Disable static IP.
      # subconfig.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.0.#{i + 10}"
      # Enable DHCP (for nodes).
      subconfig.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
    end
  end

  # Install avahi on all machines  
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get install -y avahi-daemon libnss-mdns
  SHELL

  # How do I just use dnsmasq, so students can control it
  # to learn about DNS/DHCP server configuration?
end
```

---

## Additional Work

[I've been looking into an additional article that seems related to this goal,](https://www.wamonite.com/ip-lookup-for-vagrant-private-networking.html) but it appears to be use a bare-metal DNS provider when I want my DNS/DHCP provider to be one of the `Vagrant`-generated machines (i.e. from my `Vagrantfile`).

[I found another article that might work](http://nts.strzibny.name/dns-for-your-vagrant-needs-with-landrush-libvirt-and-dnsmasq/), but I **just** want `dnsmasq` installed on the VMs, and want to avoid using additional S/W (i.e. `avahi`) if I can.

---